# Can we capture screenshot from listener and send attachment to report portal

Tags: python, robotframework, reportportal

I need to capture screenshots when tests fail without using the "run keyword if tests fail" keyword in the teardown.
Right now,  I'm trying to add:

```
if attributes['type'] == 'TEARDOWN':
    test = BuiltIn()._get_test_in_teardown('Run Keyword If Test Failed')
    if test.failed:
        screenshot_file = BuiltIn().run_keyword('AppiumLibrary.Capture page screenshot')
        BuiltIn().run_keyword('Send attachment to report portal', screenshot_file)
```

to `start_keyword` method of `reportportal.listener` but it cannot work.

The Send attachment to report portal is from report portal send attachment document.

My expectation is to capture screenshot and send an attachment to report portal by using listener.

Comment: This has been solved by using Report Portal send attachment [document](https://github.com/reportportal/client-Python#send-attachment-screenshots).
Using `Run keyword if test failed` keyword that will capture screen, then in listening we will get this screenshot from `end_keyword` method that will send attachment every capture screen keywords executed.